# C++ getting "invalid user-defined conversion" error

Tags: c++

I have an error in the following C++ code:

```
class Node
{
    int value;
    Node *prev, *next;
public:
    Node(int value = 0, Node* prev = NULL, Node* next = NULL)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->next = next;
        this->prev = prev;
    }
}


class LinkList
{
    Node head;

    void add(int value)
    {
        head = new Node(value, &head, NULL);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error inside the add function when I try to initialize the head.

> error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'Node*' to 'const Node&'
>   [-fpermissive]

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: `head` is not a pointer. You are attempting to initialize it like one.

Comment: In C++, classes end with a semi-colon.   You must end your classes with `};`.  Right now, you only have `}`, and are missing the ***;***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been correct in Java:

```
    head = new Node(value, &head, NULL);
```

In C++ it is:

```
    head = Node(value, &head, NULL);
```

Comment: So you mean that new returns a pointer to the object instead of the actual object?

Comment: @user2565010 yes, `new` allocates memory for an object.

Answer (score 0):

In class LinkList change data member

Node head;

to

```
Node *head;
```

Comment: That's not what he needs.  As you can see he passed head's reference to the constructor and the constructor takes a pointer not a double pointer.